# How to expand variables in a string

Tags: php, string

#### Problem

I'd like to expand variables in a string in the same manner that variable in a double quoted string get expanded.

```
$string = '<p>It took $replace s</>';
$replace = 40;
expression_i_look_for;
```

`$string` should become `'<p>It took 40 s</>';`

I see a obvious solution like this:

```
$string = str_replace('"', '\"', $string);
eval('$string = "$string";');
```

But I really don't like it, because eval() is insecure. Is there any other way to do this ?

#### Context

I'm building a simple templateing engine, that's where I need this.

Example Template (view_file.php)

```
<h1>$title</h1>
<p>$content</p>
```

Template rendering (simplified code):

```
$params = array('title' => ...);

function render($view_file, $params)
    extract($params)
    ob_start();
    include($view_file);
    $text = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    expression_i_look_for; // this will expand the variables in the template
    return $text;
}
```

The expansion of the variables in the template simplifies it's syntax. Without it, the above example template would be:

```
<h1><?php echo $title;?></h1>
<p><?php echo $content;?></p>
```

Do you think this approach is good ? Or should I look in another direction ?

#### Edit

Finally I understand that there is no simple solution due to flexible way PHP expands variables (even `${$var}->member[0]` would be valid.

So there are only two options:

1. Adopt an existing full fledged templating system
2. Stick with something very basic that essentially is limited to including the view files via `include`.

Comment: Why not take a look at some of the big ( or small ) PHP templating engines that exist and see how they do it. This wheel has been invented so often that I would expect to see some fairly standard solutions around by now. There may even be an extension or library that will do 90% of the work for you. Of course, the wise man now is likely to be looking at using the server just for data and doing most of the display logic on the client with JavaScript.

Comment: You're trying to build a templating system, which is what PHP already is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rather suggest using some existing template engines, like for example Smarty, but if you really want to do it by yourself you can use the simple regular expression to match all variables constructed with for example letters and numbers and then replace them with correct variables:

```
<?php

$text = 'hello $world, what is the $matter? I like $world!';

preg_match_all('/\$([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/',
    $text,
    $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

$world = 'World';
$matter = 'matter';

foreach(array_unique($out[1]) as $variable){
    $text=str_replace('$'.$variable, $$variable, $text);
}

echo $text;

?>
```

prints

> hello World, what is the matter? I like World!

Comment: Great answer tested it.

Comment: Very nice response. I had pulled out a snippet below, which might be more useful to call this routine from outer code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this?

templater.php:

```
<?php

$first = "first";
$second = "second";
$third = "third";

include('template.php');
```

template.php:

```
<?php

echo 'The '.$first.', '.$second.', and '.$third.' variables in a string!';
```

When `templater.php` is run, produces:

```
"The first, second, and third variables in a string!"
```

Comment: Please read question carefully he wants as order $string, $replace  not $replace, $string.

Comment: @Salim Reading his question, he doesn't seem to know what he's doing and may just be ordering it this way because of inexperience. Since when do you define variables you're templating for in that exact same template?

Comment: Please see @lejlot's answer, just great http://stackoverflow.com/a/18619564/2459296

Comment: @Salim it's unnecessary code. Look at my edited answer. There's no need to complicate things like that.

Answer (score 1):

### Parse

Parse the string look for `$` followed by valid variable name (i.e. [`\[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff\]\[a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff\]*`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php))

### Variable²

Use [variable variables syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) (i.e. `$$var` notation).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this ?

```
$replace = 40;
$string = '<p>It took {$replace}s</p>';
```

Comment: Variable are not expanded in [simple quote](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using single quotes

```
$string = '<p>It took $replace s</>';
$replace = 40;
```

use double quotes

```
$replace = 40;
$string = "<p>It took $replace s</>";
```

However, for readability and to enable you to remove the space between $replace and the s I would use:

```
$replace = 40;
string = '<p>It took ' . $replace . 's</>';
```

Comment: Please read question carefully he wants as order $string, $replace  not $replace, $string.

Comment: This won't work because the string comes from ob_get_contents()

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is probably to parse your document as a tree, identify your parser tags ( because you are managing your own parser they don't have to follow php conventions if you don't want them to ) and then add in your values from an associative array or other data structure as the opportunity arises.

This is a more complex solution but will make it far easier when  you realise that you want to be able to display lists whose length is unknown ahead of time using some kind of looping structure based on a standard display option. In the long run, you won't find many serious templating systems that aren't parsing the documents into some kind of in-memory tree where the placeholders can be inserted and then the document constructed as required. This also offers many opportunities for cacheing. Also, if you are unafraid of recursion you will be able to perform a lot of operations on it fairly simply.

*However,* this is not an uncommon problem to solve and as I commented on the question, there are almost guaranteed to be libraries and extensions around that provide most of the functionality you need. Unless this is a purely academic process for you, I would find some existing solutions and either use one of those or get a solid understanding of how it works so you have a starting point for adapting your own solution.

Comment: Your probably right, it is somewhat reinventing the wheel. But I don't need advanced parsing and think that my templating engine should not make more than 20 at a great maximum 40 lines.

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet I pulled out from Lejlot's answer. I tested it and it works fine.

```
function resolve_vars_in_str( $input )
{
    preg_match_all('/\$([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/', $input, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    foreach(array_unique($out[1]) as $variable) $input=str_replace('$'.$variable, $GLOBALS["$variable"], $input);
    return $input ;
}
```